# How does PostgreSQL handle multiple WHERE clauses?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, where-clause

```
where x and y and z
```

or

```
where y and z and x
```

Is there a difference in terms of performance and how does the PostgreSQL filter?
Where can I find documentation on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL question: Does the order of the WHERE clause make a difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458060/sql-question-does-the-order-of-the-where-clause-make-a-difference)

Comment: but i'm asking how does the postgresql planner handle this?

Answer (score 3):

SQL is not a procedural language. The *order* in which `WHERE` conditions appear is **completely irrelevant**. PostgreSQL will evaluate the whole expression for every row, but decide where and when to apply each expression according to the query plan.

Just make sure that you get the logic straight according to [operator precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE).

Answer (score 1):

Just prepend your query with `EXPLAIN` and you will see nice information about what planner is really planning.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-explain.html