# sql performance

Tags: sql

which sql below have better performance, and why?

1. `table A(100 rows), table B(1000 rows)`

   `(1)select * from A, B; (2) select * from B, A;`
2. `(1) select * from T;`
   `(2) select col1, col2 from T;`

Comment: I would recommend using the ANSI standard JOIN syntax: `SELECT (list of columns) FROM A INNER JOIN B ON .......` instead of the old-style `table1, table2, table3......` syntax - less danger of introducing an unwanted cartesian product!

Comment: Well here is a cartesian product, there is no WHERE clause.

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456509/tips-and-tricks-to-speed-up-an-sql

Answer (score 1):

1. The order of your tables does not matter, the same execution plan will be generated.
2. The second option will be slightly faster because less data is being transmitted to you. There's not much in it though.

Answer (score 0):

1. All databases worth their salt will have the same performance. The database optimiser will find an efficient way regardless of the order.

Note: If you have a lot of tables in your query it may be harder for the optimiser, and then you may get different results with different order.

1. (I assume that T only has 2 columns) The difference will be innoticable. In most cases you want to specify the columns as that will keep your code easier to maintain and less bug-prone.

Answer (score 0):

1: query (1) & (2) will produce the same cartesian product of 100x1000=1000x100 records, the performance is the same

1. (2) will be faster if either col1 or col2 are keys or have indexes, otherwise the faster is (1)

Comment: There's no where clause, so I believe an index won't help here.