# Increase SQL Query Performance

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have two tables. In one table we enter all types of Models, each model with around 100 rows. The second table has sales data about the first item. I need to produce a result like this:

```
Date           Model    Total(WE BOUGHT)   Sold
----------     -----    ----------------   ----
2011-01-21      M34R            300         200
2011-01-21      M71S            250          22
```

My query looks like this:

```
select distinct
   CONVERT(varchar(10),x.Scantime,120) as ScanDate,
   x.ModelNumber,
   (  Select count(*)
      from micro_model z
      where
         z.ModelNumber=x.ModelNumber
         and CONVERT(varchar(10),z.scantime,101)
            = CONVERT(varchar(10),x.Scantime,101)
   ) as Total,
   (   select COUNT(*)
       from
          micro_Model m
          inner join micro_model_sold y on m.IDNO=y.IDNO
       where
          CONVERT(varchar(10),m.scantime,101)
             = CONVERT(varchar(10),x.Scantime,101)
          and x.ModelNumber=m.ModelNumber
   ) as Sold
from maxis.dbo.maxis_IMEI_Model x 
where
    CONVERT(varchar(10),x.scantime,101) between '01/01/2011' and '01/25/2011'
```

I am able to achieve that from the above query but it is taking more than 2 minutes to execute. Please suggest how I can improve the performance. I have heard about pivot tables and indexed views but have never done them.

Comment: formatting the question properly would help alot

Comment: @ARB: What type is `scantime` field? `Date` or `Datetime` (I guess the second)? And what version of SQL-Server do you have?

Comment: Are you able to modify the schema? If so, adding a (computed, persisted, and indexed) column to these tables that removes the time portion from `scantime` may be beneficial

Comment: Look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456509/tips-and-tricks-to-speed-up-an-sql

Comment: @Damien in general I wouldn't recommend that. Most of the time production queries working with date ranges can be done without removing the time portion, it just takes some knowledge.

Comment: @ErikE - it depends on how often you're going to be performing joins between multiple tables where you want to join on only date portions - as seemed to be the case here. If you're join heavy, you want to do everything possible to make those joins indexable. I note that in your answer, you're still having to strip times to make the join work.

Comment: @Damien You're right, it depends on the usage patterns and other things. Yet, CPU is cheap, and removing times is not that expensive as long doing so isn't part of row filtering in a join, or for example forcing an eager spool when a lazy spool was possible. Going overboard adding persisted date-only columns is a potential performance danger as well, so I was just trying to present a balanced view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a very many things going on in your query that could be causing problems. There are also some areas of uncertainty that should probably be ironed out. For starters, try out this query:

```
SELECT
   DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, X.ScanTime), 0) ScanDate,
   X.ModelNumber,
   Coalesce(Z.Total, 0) Total,
   Coalesce(Z.Sold, 0) Sold
FROM
   maxis.dbo.maxis_IMEI_Model X
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
         Z.ModelNumber,
         DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, Z.ScanTime), 0) ScanDate,
         Count(DISTINCT M.IDNO) Total,
         Count(Y.IDNO) Sold
      FROM
         micro_model Z
         LEFT JOIN micro_model_sold Y
            ON Z.IDNO = Y.IDNO
      GROUP BY
         DateDiff(Day, 0, Z.ScanTime),
         Z.ModelNumber
   ) Z
      ON X.ModelNumber = Z.ModelNumber
      AND X.ScanTime >= Z.ScanDate
      AND X.ScanTime < Z.ScanDate + 1
WHERE
   X.ScanTime >= '20110101'
   AND X.ScanTime < '20110126'
```

1. Converting to character in order to do whole date comparisons (by chopping off the characters that represent the time) is very inefficient. The best practice way is to do as I have shown in the WHERE clause. Notice that I incremented the final date by one day, then made that point *exclusive* using less-than instead of less-than-or-equal-to (which is what BETWEEN does). All the joins also needed to change. Finally, when it *is* necessary to remove the time portion of a date, the DateDiff method I show here is best (there is a slightly faster method that is much harder to understand so I can't recommend it, but if you're using SQL Server 2008 you can just do `Convert(date, DateColumn)` which is the fastest of all).
2. Using the date format '01/01/2011' is not region safe. If your query is ever used on a machine where the language is changed to one that has a default date format of DMY, your dates will be interpreted incorrectly, swapping the month and day and generating errors. Use the format `yyyymmdd` to be safe.
3. Using correlated subqueries (your SELECT statements inside parentheses to pull in column values from other tables) is awkward and in some cases yields very bad execution plans. Even though the optimizer can often convert these to proper joins, there is no guarantee. It also becomes very hard for other people looking at the query to understand what it is doing. It is better to express such things using outer joins as shown. I converted the correlated subqueries to derived tables.
4. Using `DISTINCT` is troubling. Your query shouldn't be returning multiple rows for each model. If so, something is logically wrong with the query and you're probably getting incorrect data.
5. I *think* I've combined the two correlated subqueries in my derived tables correctly. But I don't have example data and all the schema information so it is my best guess. In any case, my query should give you ideas.
6. I completely reformatted your query because it was nearly impossible to see what it was doing. I encourage you to do a little more formatting in your own code. This will aid you and anyone who comes after you to understand what is going on much more quickly. If you ask more SQL questions on this site you need to format your own code better. Please do so and also use the "code block" button or simply indent all the code lines by 4 spaces manually so it will get formatted by the web page as a code block.

You know, staring at my query a little more, it's clear that I don't understand the relationship between `maxis_IMEI_Model` and the other tables. Please explain a bit more what the tables mean and what result you want to see.

It's possible the problems in my query can be solved with a simple `GROUP BY` and throwing some `SUM`s on the number columns, but I am not 100% sure. It may be that the `maxis_IMEI_Model` table needs to go away completely, or to move into its own derived table where it is grouped separately before being joined.

Comment: you are amazing Erike... Thanks a looooooooooooooooooooot

Comment: You're welcome. Did it work? Is the performance better? If there are any problems please try to answer the questions I raised about the tables and how they relate and I will try to help.

Comment: it was taking 37 secs before..Now less than 1 sec.. I mentioned the wrong table name there.. It was my fault...Any way thanks a lot dude :)

Comment: You're welcome! I hope the results are as you expected, especially the counts of different things. Please double-check!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758374/increase-sql-query-performance                                                         Hi Erike, can u pls look into it. I hv got another query. This time i am not converting Datetime but still taking around 44 secs...   and I am using one table only now. can u pls tell me what the problem could be.. Thanks. . :)... I hv checked the ur pervious query.. it is perfectly alright.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a SQL expert by any means, but you've got a *lot* of conversions in there. Why? Why do you need to convert these datetime columns (which is the type I'm assuming for `scantime` etc) into strings before comparing them?

I strongly suspect that the conversions are removing any benefit you're getting from what indexes you've got present. (You do have indexes for all the columns involved in the join, right?) In fact, both of your joins look to me like they should be joins on multiple columns without any where clauses... although I'd expect the query optimizer to treat them equivalently if possible.

Look at each and every conversion, and check whether you really need it. I suspect you don't actually need *any* of them - and the final "between" may even be doing the wrong thing at the moment, given that you're converting into a non-sortable format.

In general - not even just in SQL - it's always worth trying to deal with data in its natural form wherever possible. You're dealing with dates/times - so why treat them as strings for comparison? Conversions are a source of both performance problems *and* correctness problems.

Comment: You are right in all (except the JOINs, they cannot easily changed to equality joins as the conversions there chop off the `time` from `DateTime` fields).

Comment: @ypercube: In that case having an extra field for just the date may well be appropriate... and I suspect that a conversion from DATETIME to DATETIME dropping the date would be faster than converting everything to string representations.

Comment: Yes, exactly, as Damien's suggestion. He is joining (and trying to group by) date, so this is probably the most efficient way.