# speed up SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query which is taking some serious time to execute on anything older than the past, say, hours worth of data.  This is going to create a view which will be used for datamining, so the expectations are that it would be able to search back weeks or months of data and return in a reasonable amount of time (even a couple minutes is fine... I ran for a date range of `10/3/2011 12:00pm` to `10/3/2011 1:00pm` and it took 44 minutes!)

The problem is with the two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s in the bottom.  When I take those out, it can run in about 10 seconds.  However, those are the bread and butter of this query.

This is all coming from one table.  The ONLY thing this query returns differently than the original table is the column `xweb_range`.  `xweb_range` is a calculated field column (range) which will only use the values from `[LO,LC,RO,RC]_Avg` where their corresponding `[LO,LC,RO,RC]_Sensor_Alarm = 0` (do not include in range calculation if sensor alarm = 1)

```
WITH Alarm (sub_id, 
LO_Avg, LO_Sensor_Alarm, LC_Avg, LC_Sensor_Alarm, RO_Avg, RO_Sensor_Alarm, RC_Avg, RC_Sensor_Alarm) AS (
SELECT sub_id, LO_Avg, LO_Sensor_Alarm, LC_Avg, LC_Sensor_Alarm, RO_Avg, RO_Sensor_Alarm, RC_Avg, RC_Sensor_Alarm 
FROM dbo.some_table
where sub_id <> '0'
)
, AddRowNumbers AS (
SELECT  rowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LO_Avg)
    , sub_id
    , LO_Avg, LO_Sensor_Alarm
    , LC_Avg, LC_Sensor_Alarm
    , RO_Avg, RO_Sensor_Alarm
    , RC_Avg, RC_Sensor_Alarm
FROM Alarm
)
, UnPivotColumns AS (
SELECT rowNumber, value = LO_Avg FROM AddRowNumbers WHERE LO_Sensor_Alarm = 0
UNION ALL SELECT rowNumber, LC_Avg FROM AddRowNumbers WHERE LC_Sensor_Alarm = 0
UNION ALL SELECT rowNumber, RO_Avg FROM AddRowNumbers WHERE RO_Sensor_Alarm = 0
UNION ALL SELECT rowNumber, RC_Avg FROM AddRowNumbers WHERE RC_Sensor_Alarm = 0
)
SELECT rowNumber.sub_id
   , cds.equipment_id
   , cds.read_time
   , cds.LC_Avg
   , cds.LC_Dev
   , cds.LC_Ref_Gap
   , cds.LC_Sensor_Alarm
   , cds.LO_Avg
   , cds.LO_Dev
   , cds.LO_Ref_Gap
   , cds.LO_Sensor_Alarm
   , cds.RC_Avg
   , cds.RC_Dev
   , cds.RC_Ref_Gap
   , cds.RC_Sensor_Alarm
   , cds.RO_Avg
   , cds.RO_Dev
   , cds.RO_Ref_Gap
   , cds.RO_Sensor_Alarm
   , COALESCE(range1.range, range2.range) AS xweb_range
FROM   AddRowNumbers rowNumber
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT rowNumber, range = MAX(value) - MIN(value) FROM UnPivotColumns GROUP BY rowNumber HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) range1 ON range1.rowNumber = rowNumber.rowNumber
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT rowNumber, range = AVG(value) FROM UnPivotColumns     GROUP BY rowNumber HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) range2 ON range2.rowNumber = rowNumber.rowNumber
   INNER JOIN dbo.some_table cds
   ON rowNumber.sub_id = cds.sub_id
```

Comment: I think this is an acceptable question.  But, you need to post your table schema, and information about any indices you have set up.

Comment: First most obvious question - **Is there an index on `Rownumber INCLUDE (value)`?**

Comment: Also, you know `CTE`s are just disposable views, right?  There is no performance benefit?  You basically have 3 levels of nested views  that you are aggregating here...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456509/tips-and-tricks-to-speed-up-an-sql

Comment: @JNK, thanks for the information.  Excuse my ignorance as I'm not a DBA, but who could we put an index on    Rownumber INCLUDE (value).  Rownumber is created on the fly?

Also, I used CTE's because I couldn't find any better solution to this problem.  If anyone has an entirely different approach that does the same thing -- I'm all ears.  Thanks

Comment: @Tom - looks like you can't index it, which is probably the source of the problem.   You may want to consider materializing this to a `#TEMP` table, indexing it, then querying those `#temp` tables.  It may still be MUCH faster than the CTE solution even with the table creation/indexing overhead.

Comment: @JNK, I switched all CTEs to # tables and the same query that took 44 minutes ran in less than one second.  Are CTE's really that bad?  It makes no sense to me.

The new problem is creating this into a view, as views don't play nice with # tables.  

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Is not that CTEs are bad, its just what @JNK said, they are just diposable views, they don't have any indexes.

Comment: Looks like you can combine the Alarm and AddRownumber CTEs.  Still same problem - no index on a CTE.  You might need to materialize to SELECT rowNumber, range = ... as that is the join.  And you may need to materialize at both levels.  Declare a PK on the #temps and when you populate the #temps sort on the PK.

Comment: @Tom: I answered your comment and revised my query to try to show more clearly what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to understand exactly what your query is trying to do without knowing the domain.  However, it seems to me like your query is simply trying to find, for each row in `dbo.some_table` where `sub_id` is not 0, the range of the following columns in the record (or, if only one matches, that single value):

- LO_AVG when LO_SENSOR_ALARM=0
- LC_AVG when LC_SENSOR_ALARM=0
- RO_AVG when RO_SENSOR_ALARM=0
- RC_AVG when RC_SENSOR_ALARM=0

You constructed this query assigning each row a sequential row number, unpivoted the _AVG columns along with their row number, computed the range aggregate grouping by row number and then joining back to the original records by row number.  CTEs don't materialize results (nor are they indexed, as discussed in the comments).  So each reference to `AddRowNumbers` is expensive, because `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LO_Avg)` is a sort.

Instead of cutting this table up just to join it back together by row number, why not do something like:

```
SELECT cds.sub_id
   , cds.equipment_id
   , cds.read_time
   , cds.LC_Avg
   , cds.LC_Dev
   , cds.LC_Ref_Gap
   , cds.LC_Sensor_Alarm
   , cds.LO_Avg
   , cds.LO_Dev
   , cds.LO_Ref_Gap
   , cds.LO_Sensor_Alarm
   , cds.RC_Avg
   , cds.RC_Dev
   , cds.RC_Ref_Gap
   , cds.RC_Sensor_Alarm
   , cds.RO_Avg
   , cds.RO_Dev
   , cds.RO_Ref_Gap
   , cds.RO_Sensor_Alarm

   --if the COUNT is 0, xweb_range will be null (since MAX will be null), if it's 1, then use MAX, else use MAX - MIN (as per your example)
   , (CASE WHEN stats.[Count] < 2 THEN stats.[MAX] ELSE stats.[MAX] - stats.[MIN] END) xweb_range

FROM dbo.some_table cds

    --cross join on the following table derived from values in cds - it will always contain 1 record per row of cds
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(Value), MAX(Value)
        FROM
        (
            --construct a table using the column values from cds we wish to aggregate
            VALUES (LO_AVG, LO_SENSOR_ALARM),
                   (LC_AVG, LC_SENSOR_ALARM),
                   (RO_AVG, RO_SENSORALARM),
                   (RC_AVG, RC_SENSOR_ALARM)


        ) x (Value, Sensor_Alarm) --give a name to the columns for _AVG and _ALARM
        WHERE Sensor_Alarm = 0 --filter our constructed table where _ALARM=0

    ) stats([Count], [Min], [Max]) --give our derived table and its columns some names

WHERE cds.sub_id <> '0' --this is a filter carried over from the first CTE in your example
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts on this.  I'd like to try this method, however I'm getting an error near VALUES.  I'm not sure the correct syntax for that part of the code as I've never seen something like you're doing.  What is this technique called?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2008?  The `VALUES` keyword is the Table Value Constructor.  The documentation is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx and you can see a similar use as a derived table in a `FROM` clause in Example C.

Comment: Also, if you're unable to use `VALUES`, it may be due to your SQL Compatibility Level being set to some value other than 100 (SQL 2008).  You could also replace `VALUES ...` with `SELECT LO_AVG, LO_SENSOR_ALARM UNION ALL SELECT LC_AVG, LC_SENSOR_ALARM UNION ALL ...`

Comment: Awesome stuff @Michael.  I ended up doing a UNION on the selects instead of VALUES.  Not sure why VALUES wouldn't work for me, I am on SQL 2008.  This query went from taking 5+ minutes to run for yesterdays data to running in seconds on data from over a month ago.  Really appreciate it.