# Change SQL query to explicitly control the execution sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

Say I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM tb1
WHERE col1 = 1
 AND col2 = 2
```

Assume `col1` is more selective and the engine will normally execute `col1 = 1` firstly to gain better performance. If the conditions become more complicated, the engine may easy to make the wrong decision. So I want to control the execution sequence explicitly, how can I make it?

I guess one way may work. Firstly query

```
SELECT * FROM tb1
WHERE col1 = 1
```

select the result into a temp table, then filter by `col2 = 2`, but as the conditions grow more and more, of course it's impossible to create so many temp table. Any ideas?

Update 1

People say the optimizer always makes the right decision on which filter should be executed firstly to gain better performance, but I still suspect it can work 100% of the time as the query grows larger and more complicated.

Another question, can I change the execution order by subquery or CTE? like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE col1 = 1
)t
WHERE col2 = 2
```

Comment: I don't think the order of execution of the two `AND` conditions is under your control in SQL Server.

Comment: `the engine may easy to make the wrong decision` ... what does this mean?

Comment: I would avoid trying to outsmart the hundreds of thousands of man hours invested in the SQL Server query optimizer until you see an actual problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, say the engine may first exec `col2 = 2` then `col1=1`

Comment: @BartMao - SQL Server understands the idea of some columns being more selective than others. It may well figure this out on its own, without you needing to do anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the order of columns in a WHERE clause matter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642784/does-the-order-of-columns-in-a-where-clause-matter)

Comment: If the complexity grows, you will definitely not do a better job than the SQL Server engine.  Also consider that as the data changes (maybe the selectivity changes) and the stats are updated, SQL Server can adapt to the changes and change the execution plan as needed. It cannot do this if you force a certain execution strategy.

Comment: You're using a declarative language (one where you express what you need, not how to accomplish it), so in principle what you're asking for is a SQL Anti-Pattern.  That said, you do have some tools.  On SQLServer they're HINTS, which allow you to specify indexes to be used, types of join algorithm (NestedLoop, Merge, Hash), etc.  But probably your best tool is simply to ensure you have the right indexes and have kept the database's statistics up to date, possibly also the WITH RECOMPILE option.  But based on your notional description, this strikes me as Premature Optimisation.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually SQL Optimizer can find the better plan, but if you want to fix it, there are options...

You may create a test data set for which SQL engine chooses correct (desired) plan, then you can extract the query plan to XML string (see SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON
) and finally use WITH PLAN option (query hint) to fix the plan.

Keep in mind that query will fail if you change the schema in the future without updating the plan.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you should use query hints.

1. You can use `USE PLAN` query hint.
2. Use `with(index(index_name))` created for specific row order.

For the first point you have to get XML plan by first executing your query in which you are getting your desired execution order. And for second one, just create index on those columns in which you have arranged column in desired order.